# Are they the same "She is drying her hair off" and "She is drying her hair up"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> **[dry](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dry-up)** 4 PLATES/DISHES ETC British English to rub plates, dishes etc dry
>   with a cloth after they have been washed
>   **dry something ↔ up**
>
> I’ll just dry up these mugs and we can have a coffee.

---

> **[dry off](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dry-off)** | dry somebody/something  off ​to become dry or make something
>   dry
>
> We went swimming and then lay in the sun to dry off.
>
> We dried our boots off by the fire.

---

It seems that British people use "**dry something ↔ up**" to talk about drying plates or dishes, but the above dictionary doesn't limit it to plates or dishes, it could be "**hair**" or "**car**", etc.

I am not sure if British people say "**She is drying her hair up**"

While "**dry something / somebody off**" can be used by both British & American people, right?

So, we can say "**She is drying the dishes / the car / her hair off**" right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. "Drying up" is idiomatically limited to kitchen things.  The dictionary intends a limited meaning when it says "plates, dishes etc" - you should treat that "etc" as referring to crockery, cutlery, glasses, mugs, pans, etc; not hair, car, etc.  Drying up is the counterpart of washing up, which we also only use for plates, dishes etc.  We say "*She's washing the car / her hair*", not "*she's washing up the car / her hair*".  So accordingly we would say "*drying the car off*" (or simply "*drying the car*"), and not "*drying up the car*".

Comment: That is interesting and clear.

Comment: _Dry up_ can also have the meaning of _make [something] excessively dry_.  'The hot weather has dried up the lawn.'